# maximum excecution time limit error when importing big excell and update db

Tags: php, laravel

I have excell file with book_id and price . So I need import this excell and if price in excell different from price in database then update price in it . There 1600 books in excell.

First I thied like this

```
namespace App\Imports;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class BookImport implements ToModel
{
   public function model(array $row)
   {

    if($book = \App\Models\Book::find($row[0])) {

        if($book->paperbook_price!=$row[5]){
            $book->paperbook_price = $row[5];
        }
        if($book->ebook_price!=$row[6]){
            $book->ebook_price = $row[6];
        }
        if($book->audio_price!=$row[7]){
            $book->audio_price = $row[7];
        }
        $book->save();

         return $book;
    }
}
}
```

Then I get maximum execution time limit 30 second  error .

Then I decided to create temporarly table 'temp_books' and import all excell rows to it . then compare prices and update original 'books' table.

```
namespace App\Imports;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class BookImport implements ToModel
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
         return \App\Models\TempBooks::create([
            'id'=>$row[0],
            'paperbook_price'=>$row[5],
            'ebook_price'=>$row[6],
            'audio_price'=>$row[7]
        ]);
    }
}
```

But getting Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4198400 bytes) error .

So is there way to do this. Books count will be increased .

Comment: Why not use a higher time or memory limit? 134 MB is not that much. Or use a CLI script to import the data

Answer (score 0):

1600 is not a big number of entries and should not require huge amount of time and memory.

Here some hints to improve this:

You can use chunk reading to reduce the required memory (like 100 at a time): https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html

Check also Batch inserts and upserts that way you can save more memory and time: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/batch-inserts.html

If you need at the end still more memory and execution time, then you have to increase that in your php.ini configuration on the server.
Here example with 120 seconds and 256 mega bytes:

```
max_execution_time = 120
memory_limit = 256M
```